# Adding Required in input field AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, required

I have used `<required>` inside `<input>`.Also I tried using ng-required="true". But the modal closes itself even if the required field is left empty. Whenever this modal closes,

> Please fill out this fielld

shows up but modal gets dismissed even with blank input fields.
See [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/zO72aCH8UBQSdH3II6Mr?p=preview)

How do I make sure that the form is filled completely before this form is submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `required` and `ng-required` attributes only affect the validity of a form. If you want to prevent your modal buttons from working you'll need to hook up the form's state to something like `ng-disabled`. Check this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ru4uqgpcWKyGwCFfZPoO?p=preview

You'll see that I wrapped your modal body in a form named "eventForm", and added `ng-disabled="eventForm.$invalid"` to your "OK" button.

You can read more about forms in Angular here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms